# Forçar a mudança do html usando Javascript

Tags: javascript

Tenho um sistema que preciso mudar alguns campos usando JS, o problema e que o type não está mudando, porque o sistema gera automaticamente o css :

Código atual:

```
<div id="div_Contrato__AdicionarParteExtra__" class="field_container" style="position: absolute; white-space: nowrap;top: 183.0px;left: 1069.0px;width: 131.0px;height: 28.0px;" onmouseover="showHideHelp(this, true);" onmouseout="showHideHelp(this, false);">
  <input type="checkbox" name="var_Contrato__AdicionarParteExtra__" errorspan="err_var_Contrato__AdicionarParteExtra__" id="var_Contrato__AdicionarParteExtra__"
    value="false" onchange="changeBooleanCheckboxValue(this)">
    <span>( + ) Adicionar Parte</span><input type="hidden" name="var_Contrato__AdicionarParteExtra__" value="false"><span style="width: 17px; padding-left: 1px;"><img id="help_Contrato__AdicionarParteExtra__" width="16" 
height="16" src="/imagens/icones_final/information_16x16-trans.png" 
title="Adicionar uma parte extra" style="display: none;"></span></div>
```

Mudanças na abertura da página:

```
  var divAdicionar = document.getElementById('div_Contrato__AdicionarParteExtra__'),
      elementosFilhos = divAdicionar.childNodes;

  elementosFilhos[3].innerHTML = '';
  elementosFilhos[1].type = 'button';
  elementosFilhos[1].value = '(+) Adicionar';
  elementosFilhos[1].className += 'btn btn-success';
```

O `type` não está sendo alterado